$a = v \frac{dv}{dx}$. So how can $a \neq 0$ when $v=0$?
By chain rule: $$ \ddot x = \frac{d \dot x}{dt} = \frac{d \dot x}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = \dot x \frac{d \dot x}{dx}$$
I like to interpret this in the context of motion along the x-axis. So velocity, $v = \dot x$ and acceleration, $a = \ddot x$. $$a = v \frac{dv}{dx}$$
But this seems to imply that $v=0 \implies a=0$, and I know this isn't true!
So what's wrong with the equation!?

You multiply and divide by $dx$ that is zero is case when $v=0$ because $v=\dot x$

If $v$ is $0$, then $a$ is certainly $0$, as $a = \dot v$, and the derivative of the $0$ function is the $0$ function.

Actually, I have just found this question is answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168066/351157

@DanielP What if $v=0$ instantaneously? e.g. SHM.

Or @DanielP are you trying to make a point that I should be more careful to make it clear that $v$ in't the $0$ function - I mean that $v=0$ at some, specifc value(s) of $t$ - not all.

In SHM you have $v^2=\omega^2\left(a^2-x^2\right)$, so $v\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\omega^2x$. When $v=0$ in SHM, $x$ is maximised/minimised and so isn't $0$, so the $RHS\ne0$. Therefore you have an undefined value of $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}$, so you don't know if $a=0$ by using $v\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}$.
